# Как изменить переменную из метода в классе?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите как можно изменить переменные в "**init**" из метода "update_A", в чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Boris'
        self.age = 12
        
    def update_A(self):
        self.name = 'Ivan'
        self.age = 30
        
X = A().update_A
print(X.name(), X.age())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вам надо вызвать `update_A`. У вас `self.name` и `self.age` это не методы поэтому надо убрать круглые скобки

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Boris'
        self.age = 12
        
    def update_A(self):
        self.name = 'Ivan'
        self.age = 30
        
X = A()
X.update_A() 
print(X.name, X.age)
```

а если хотите чтобы работало в одну строку то надо добавить `return self` в конец метода `update_A`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Boris'
        self.age = 12
        
    def update_A(self):
        self.name = 'Ivan'
        self.age = 30
        return self

X = A().update_A() 
print(X.name, X.age)
```

Comment: Но надо бы код пояснять. Не у всех в мозгу встроенный `diff` по картинке кода работает )

Comment: Большое спасибо всем неравнодушным, очень помогли!!

Answer (score 4):

Ну, все методы вызываются с помощью `()`. То есть, ваш вызов должен быть:

`X = A().update_A()`

Это должно сработать.

И добавьте ещё `return self` в конце метода, иначе не будет работать в одну строку и придётся делать так:

```
X = A()
X.update_A()
```

Comment: `self` надо оставить

Comment: @Danis, ну, я просто давно уже не прогал по полной, т.к. 10 класс, подготовка к ЕГЭ и тд и тп, потому и засомневался

Comment: @DGDays Ну надо всё же помнить, что есть переменные самого класса и есть переменные экземпляра класса. Как-раз это `self` и позволяет работать с переменными экземпляра.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну, понимаю что надо всё помнить. Но также надо знать алгебру, геометрию, физику, русский и тд, иначе в хороший ВУЗ не поступить + Эта ненавистная дистанционка, на которой вообще ничего не объясняют и приходится самому всё изучать. Понимаю что виноват и тд, но сейчас вот прям просто мозги не варят уже.... Остаётся только молиться и танцевать с бубном, чтобы выпустили очно учиться, может хоть тогда полегче станет